# Can't install Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 (RC3) on Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, installation, windows-server, sql-server-2016

I am attempting to install Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 (RC3) on Windows Server 2008 R2.

I have removed all other versions of SQL Server, and removed VS 2015 Community and all it's SQL Server components.

When I run setup from the SQLServer2016RC3-x64-ENU.iso, (downloaded from Microsoft, and successfully installed on Windows 10, with VS 2015 Community installed), I get a dialogue with the following message:

> Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 (RC3) Setup:
>   Setup limited to Reporting Services for SharePoint
>   This server is running Windows Server 2008 R2. You can continue with setup to install or upgrade Reporting
>   Services functionality in SharePoint:
>   0 Reporting Services - SharePoint
>   0 Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint Products

The server does not have SharePoint installed.  Why is this happening, and how can I install Microsoft SQL Server 2016 Release Candidate 3 on this server?

Answer (score 7):

I found the answer here:

[Warning Setup Limited to Reporting Services for SharePoint](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/Troubleshooting154.htm) by Alberto Morillo

Which, in short, says:

> The only SQL Server 2016 features allowed to install on Windows Server 2008 R2 are Reporting Services (SharePoint) and Reporting Services Add-in for SharePoint products as mentioned on the "Hardware and Software Requirements for Installing SQL Server 2016" article created for SQL Server 2016 Preview (CTP versions).
>
> You won't be able to install the Database Engine or any other feature because they are not supported on Windows Server 2008 R2.